# Angular 2 / two child components have same scope?

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have 2 same child components in the parent component. Child components have the same scope meaning that they share same variables and functions.

```
<level-range-table [selectedElement]="selectedElement" ></level-range-table>
<level-range-table [selectedElement]="selectedElement2" ></level-range-table>
```

In the child component, I have button `onclick` that show/hide the table. When I press button both tables are hidden.

Is it possible to have 2 different instances of the same child component?

Comment: No they don't. But if you don't show your code, there's no way we can explain why it has this problem, and how to fix it.

Comment: Still no. They have their own components class instance and don't share if you don't specify to share.

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right, I found a bug, it seems that I shared variable by accident. after few hours of debugging I begun to doubt in laws of physics and angular2. sorry for inconvenience